# How to configure Win10 firewall to block outbound connections without a rule, but still allow Windows Update?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-update

For those of us that prefer to have Windows Firewall set to "Block Outbound connections that do not have a rule": What rule(s) need to be added to allow Windows Update to still work?

I've tried adding rules for Windows Update service, BFE, BITS, but the Windows Update still gives the error message "We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet."  Windows Troubleshooter just wants to unblock all traffic.

Any suggestions other than just allowing all outbound traffic?  Thanks!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/50620/what-host-names-and-ports-would-need-to-be-opened-in-a-firewall-to-allow-windows

Comment: Thanks but wow that would be complicated to configure and maintain.  Windows firewall needs the IP addresses, not the domain name...

Answer (score 0):

The same here. It was working fine in Vista, but in W10 it just isn't. The only working config so far is to make an outbound rule "Allow this program" "%SystemRoot%\System32\svchost.exe".

Comment: I don't have a W10 to test, but if I had this issue, i would go about debugging it like this:  
Enable firewall block auditing - http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/Security/EnablingWindowsFirewallauditlogging.html  
Check the Security log for the most current Audit Failure. Note the Process ID.
Use Process Explorer to find which process it is. If it's svchost.exe, look what services are inside. Use ````sc config <name> type= own```` to isolate an idividual service to narrow it down further. This should help find the missing service.